# UITextField is being drawn twice on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

I'm programmatically adding a UITextField to a Horizontal UIStackView, which is inside a Vertical UIStackView, but it gets displayed with both rounded and sharp corners.

What I think the problem is is that the UITextField is being drawn twice, first with the default appearance and then with the custom appearance that I added to its layer.

The UITextField looks like this

[image: UITextField]

If you look closely, you can see that the sharp corners color is the default one, while the rest of the border is darker.

The code that I use to modify its appearance is the following

```
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0    
myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
```

I think I'm missing something but I'm not sure what. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Before those lines of code, I call the UITextField initializer with no parameters like this

```
myTextField = UITextField()
```

**EDIT 2**
This is the entire code relating to the TextField

```
myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
myTextField.clipsToBounds = true

myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

// Create the constraints
constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: horizontalStackView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: verticalStackView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

// Add the components to the Horizontal Stack View
horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(myTextField)
horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(myStepper) // A stepper that resides next to the conflicting TextField
verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
```

Comment: Can you add the code you’re using to create the text field? It does look like it’s drawing an extra border, but the default border style is “none” so that seems odd.

Comment: Hi Noah. Besides the code in the question, there is only the call to the initializer with no parameters.

Comment: are you able to share the code on how you are adding it to your stack view? Do you have anything set in the xcode attributes inspector?

Comment: @CarlosM. - you must have something else going on. Try your code in a new view controller, where all you add is the stack view with (I'm assuming) your label and your text field. If you don't see the "extra sharp corners" then you *know* there's something else in your code that is causing it. Also, use Debug View Hierarchy to inspect what's actually there.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I added the code. I'm not editing the view directly in a storyboard so there isn't a Attribute Inspector

Comment: Please clarify valueTextField and myTextField , these are different correct? Or have you linked your textView to two identities?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri My bad. It's the same TextField, I changed the name in the original code for better understanding but I forgot to change it on the last edit

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your subviews to your stack view like this.

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myTextView, myStepper])
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
```

Also add in this

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

perhaps there is something funky with your constraints from the two stackviews

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
myTextField.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: This isn’t a good way to work around an issue like this—there’s a performance cost to `clipsToBounds`. A better solution would be a way to stop the second border from being drawn in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Sh_Khan solution and it worked, but after reading the comments I decided to try something else so there would be no performance cost. After commenting that line of code (the clipToBounds one) and running the app again, the corners didn't show up.

I'm completely positive there is no other change besides adding that line, running the app, and then commenting the same line out.

I'm not really sure what the problem (or even the solution) was. Maybe all I needed to do was to clean the build folder (`Product -> Clean Build Folder`) but that doesn't make sense to me.